# How to know Scroll event has finished with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: do an action after user is done scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289473/javascript-do-an-action-after-user-is-done-scrolling)

the `Scroll` event fires when the user starts scrolling the page, right? How to know if he is finished then? I want to call a function after the scrolling has done. Does anyone has any idea?

Thanks!

P.S. With jQuery please, but pure JS is also okay.

Comment: No. A `scroll` event fires every time the page has moved a single pixel. Check out [fire scroll event only once per second](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9613594/1048572)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I don't want to use $.doTimeout

Comment: @Bergi thanks, but do you have any reference for that? It seems that it just fires when you start scrolling and not continuously ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4289550/612202 then take this one

Comment: @Mahdi: Don't think you get around it. Any solution will most likely contain timeout code.

Comment: @Mahdi: Um, yes, not for literally every pixel but for every scroll move (3 lines?). If you don't want to use the plugin, you can will still need to program its functionality

Comment: @FrançoisWahl oh no, there should be something ... :(

Comment: @Bergi I want to know if there is any native and original event for that, not tricks ...

Comment: @DanLee I KNOW they timeouts are native in JS, I mean a native EVENT ... but it seems, there is no event, thanks! no need to be angry ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this using `setTimeout`. you can change timeout (im using 100) value according to your requirement.

```
var timeoutId;
$(selector).scroll(function(){
  if(timeoutId ){
         clearTimeout(timeoutId );  
  }
  timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
   // your code 
  }, 100);

});
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any other way except setting up Timeouts? I mean something native and originally for that?

Comment: timeout *are* native, it's not any plugin.

Comment: @Mahdi at the moment there isn't.

Comment: I'd give it a slightly longer timeout personally - 200ms is a bit more realistic IMO :)

Comment: @DanLee I know they are native, I meant native event like 'onScrollFinished' or something similar ...

Comment: @Mahdi No because that makes no sense. A 'scroll' is a tiny bit of rolling down, it can be a millisecond or a few seconds, you have to check manually if the user isn't scrolling anymore. Of course you can *emulate* this and create your own event out of it.

Comment: works for me. thanks :)