# AJAX callback is super-slow?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm experimenting a bit with AJAX and have successfully deployed a simple AJAX A-synced function, yet when I'm changing it to use callback method - suddenly, it takes ages to load (about 10 - 15 mins...).
Here's the function that executes right away:

```
function ajaxf() {
var xmlhttp;
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 && document.getElementById("icons")==null)
    {
    document.getElementById("text-12").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","http://some-url/ajax.php",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And here's the **way slower** iteration using a callback function:

```
function ajaxf(url,cfunc) {

  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
document.body.onscroll = function ajaxb() {
  ajaxf("http://some-url/ajax.php",function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 && document.getElementById("icons")==null)
    {
    document.getElementById("text-4").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  });
}
```

Other (perhaps) relevant details - the ajax.php file weighs merely 532 B, on my local test server both run more or less equally the same, the first function uses onscroll="ajaxf()" inside the body tag...

I was under the impression AJAX would be a little more snappy???

Comment: You are firing off a request on scroll. Put a `console.log()` in there to see how often that fires.

Comment: You will be getting a zillion onscroll events.  The slowness is probably because of the huge number of ajax requests you are launching.

Comment: Here is how to defer the scroll callback: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007957/jquery-resize-scroll-good-practice-to-use-variables/27008629#27008629

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys, with your help I was able to sort it out... for the sake of future reference I'll write my conclusions as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, thanks to @jasen's tip I've put a console.log() and was able to see the scroll function fiered a gazillion times just like @jfriend00 said.
Initially, I thought that by putting "*document.getElementById("icons")==null*" as a condition - the function would only fire once but I was wrong of course,

**So the solution was / is:** 
to reset the onscroll action after the first execution by adding "*document.body.onscroll = null;*" at the end of the function.