# How to call function after javascript .scroll()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

**Description**

I want to call a function **after** the javascript .scroll() function has finished.

**Code**

The interesting part is the javascript:

```js
const vertScroll = document.getElementById('boxSlider');

$("#btnLeft").on("click", () => {
        vertScroll.scroll({
            left: vertScroll.scrollLeft - 120,
            behavior: "smooth"
        });
        
        //This should print out the new value of 
        //vertScroll but instead always prints the value
        //before scroll()
        console.log(vertScroll.scrollLeft);
});
     
$("#btnRight").on("click", () => {
        vertScroll.scroll({
            left: vertScroll.scrollLeft + 120,
            behavior: "smooth"
        });
        
        //same as above
        console.log(vertScroll.scrollLeft);
});
```

```css
.boxSlider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxSlider" class="boxSlider">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box">Box 5</div>
  <div class="box">Box 6</div>
  <div class="box">Box 7</div>
  <div class="box">Box 8</div>
  <div class="box">Box 9</div>
  <div class="box">Box 10</div>
</div>

<input id="btnLeft" type="Button" value="Scroll left"/>
<input id="btnRight" type="Button" value="Scroll right" />
```

**Expected Behaviour**

console.log(...) should output the scroll value after the scroll() function has completed.

**Not the answer**

Don't just do console.log(scrollLeft - 120) (or +120) since I want to implement more complex code there and the console.log() is just for better understanding.

**What I've tried**

I've looked at the scroll() docs ([mozilla scroll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll)) and it doesn't seem to have a callback function.

**Question**

How can I achieve the expected behaviour?

TIA

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you, since you are already using jQuery https://stackoverflow.com/a/4289567/9184970

Comment: Maybe you are looking for offset()....

Comment: @Fili_81 .offset() doesn't work either

Comment: look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701311/event-when-user-stops-scrolling

Comment: @s.kuznetsov can you point out how this can help with my problem?

Comment: As tagged [jquery] - use https://api.jquery.com/animate which does have a callback